# how to use vlookup or index-match to pull multiple values assigned to the same "lookup value"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set with range A4:S3365. My lookup value is A3 and I am trying to search or lookup the value in column E and return data on column A. however, multiple data in column A are assigned to the same lookup value in A3 and so when I do an index match function, it only returns the first value that it finds. It does not keep return other values in Column A that are also assigned to A3.

Can you help to fix this?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
INDEX(Tempxxl!$A$4:$A$3365,MATCH($A3,Tempxxl!$E$4:$E$3365,0))
```

When I run this code, I get the same value returned multiple times. I will like all the values in column A assigned to the lookup value in A3 to be listed out when i drag the formula down.

Comment: You mention you need multiple values, then. How? In one cell? That would correspond to @Ralph's answer. Or do you have a *column/row* where you want the multiple values returned?

Comment: Hi I have assigned column A on another sheet to enter the values. Basically, i am pulling the data from Sheet named "Tempxxl" to Column A in another sheet. I will then use the data to pull more data in

Comment: Is there a possibility for one auxiliary column?

Comment: If yes, please provide the first row number of column A that will have the result, and also the column letter of the auxiliary row.

Comment: Based on your comment in the answer provided by Ralph, VBA would be most efficient. You could always try returning the nth value of index/match: https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest version of Excel including the function `=TextJoin()` then the following solution should work:

```
{=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,IF(Tempxxl!$E$4:$E$3365=$A3,Tempxxl!$A$4:$A$3365,""))}
```

Please note that this is an array formula and must be entered as such. That means that you should not enter the curved brackets but only everything inside the curved brackets and then press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`. Excel will then add automatically the curved brackets.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. I didnt know you could actually do this with excel. However, I am not pulling the data into a cell. the situation is this. I autogenerate project reports that contain a whole bunch of things that i do not want. I want to use a staff's name to pull his projects into a new sheet. Forexample, I want to pull all the projects that are being handled by Andy for example into a column A in a new sheet. And then i will use the projects to pull the rest of the information that i need using an index match function.